# If $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j (e^t)^j=0$ for all $t$, then $a_j = 0$ for all $j$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Consider the series:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j (e^t)^j=0 $$
for $t \in (-t_0,t_0)$ and $t_0>0$. How could I argue for $a_j=0$ for all $j$?

Maybe I consider this as an infinite polynomial in $x:=e^t$, which can only be zero if all coefficient $a_j$ are $0$.

Is this possible?

Alternative:

$$f^{n}(0)= \sum_{j=n}^{\infty} \frac{j!}{(j-n)!} 0^{k-n}=n! a_n$$

Comment: If $t=0$, $a_0=1$, $a_1=-1$ and all the other $a_j$ are zero what do we get?

Comment: Ok you are right. If I consider the nth deriative I get that all coefficient has to be 0. Why do we get to different results?

Comment: You did not say for what values of $t$ the equation is supposed to hold.

Comment: You get different results because you started with different assumptions. The equation $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(e^t)^j$ might mean that this equation holds for one value of $t$ (like the $t=0$ in the comment by @JohnDouma) or that it holds for all values of $t$, or at least all values sufficiently near 0, so that you can differentiate it. A clear statement of the question should lead to an unambiguous answer.

Comment: I edited my question. This should hold in an intervall around 0.

Comment: How could I argue then. Either the polynomial or the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches work.

If $g(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ then the radius of convergence of $g$ is (at least) $e^{t_0}$. Since $g$ vanishes in the nondegenerate interval $e^{-t_0} < x < e^{t_0}$ it must vanish everywhere, so its coefficients vanish.

*Proving* that vanishing power series have vanishing coefficients can be done using derivatives, like your second approach.